# CSS: Текст внутри блока отображается за его пределами

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему текст внутри `div` отображается за его пределами? Заметил, что это происходит после того как к классу `label_class` добавить свойство `float: left`. Как можно решить эту проблему? Заранее спасибо!

```css
        #content {
            position:relative;
            border: 1px solid green;
            height: auto;
        }

        .div_class {
            position:relative;
            width:200px;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }

        .label_class{
            width: 50px;
            float: left;
        }
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div class="div_class">
        <label class="label_class">1</label>
        <label class="label_class">2</label>
        <label class="label_class">3</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте css-свойство overflow:hidden

```css
        #content {
            position:relative;
            border: 1px solid green;
            height: auto;
        }

        .div_class {
            overflow: hidden;
            position:relative;
            width:200px;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }

        .label_class{
            width: 50px;
            float: left;
        }
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div class="div_class">
        <label class="label_class">1</label>
        <label class="label_class">2</label>
        <label class="label_class">3</label>
    </div>
</div>
```